# How to stop rounding decimals with double in c

Tags: c

I know this problem has been on the internet for a while but i cant seem to find how to stop my program from rounding the 3rd decimal.

the answer output is 4524.370 and should be 4524.369

also, i know my equations are stupid and could be simplified but im lazy

```
//Tanner Oelke CSE155E

 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<math.h>

 int main(void){

    double v, t; //base variables
    double sq1, sq2; //calculation variable for square root

    printf("Please enter the given air temperature in Fahrenheit:");
    scanf("%lf", &t);

    //unessecary equations but it works
    sq1=(57*t+297);
    sq2=(sq1/247);
    v=1086*sqrt(sq2);

    printf("%.3lf\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what the *input* is.

Comment: You explicitly tell your program to round to the third decimal place.  That's what the `.3` in `printf()` format `""%.3lf\n"` means.  If you want the unrounded value then omit the `.3` part.  You will probably get a result to about 11 decimal places.  Note, however, that that's still subject to rounding inherent in floating-point arithmetic and in computing floating-point approximations to the values of transcendental functions.

Comment: Yes, but i need to shorten the decimal place to 3 spots without rounding. what should i do to get 3 decimal spots without rounding?

Comment: What is the source of the formula?

Answer (score 1):

With an input of "70.0"  the result is 4524.369754... which displays as "4524.370" - What OP gets.

With an input of "69.999975"  the result is 4524.369002... which displays as "4524.369" - what OP wants.

If OP expects "70.0" to result in "4524.369", then some minor adjustment to the formula is needed.  The precision of `double` is at least 10 significant digits and often is 15+.  Even doing this in `float` then `f(70.0)--> 4524.370`.

Else OP has the wrong expectation.

---

Response to OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445882/how-to-stop-rounding-decimals-with-double-in-c#comment52756419_32445882):

"to shorten the decimal place to 3 spots without rounding".  Hmmm seems strange to want this:

```
// properly rounded result    
printf("%.3lf\n", v);
// shorten to 3 places without rounding
double v3 = floor(v*1000.0)/1000.0;
printf("%.3lf\n", v3);
```