# How to make your result on divide number is not rounded?

Tags: c

Example (in C):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b = 999;
    float c = 0.0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    c = (float)a/b; 
    printf("%.3lf...", c);
    return 0;
}
```

If I put 998 it will come out 0.999, but I want the result be 0.998; how?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - That "duplicate" is way, waay, waaay over(ab)used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop rounding decimals with double in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445882/how-to-stop-rounding-decimals-with-double-in-c)

Comment: `c = (int)(0.001+a*1000.0/b)/999.999;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round floating point numbers to the nearest integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570934/how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-to-the-nearest-integer-in-c)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: This question as stated has nothing to do with floating-point arithmetic. Proof: If the `float` and `double` types implemented perfect real-number arithmetic, the division would yield exactly .998998998…, and then formatting it to three decimal digits would produce “.999”. So the question is requesting a truncate-instead-of-round formatting, not a change to or fix for floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Side note: I would not use `%lf` to print a `float` value.  (It works, but it's doubly misleading.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to truncate instead of round.

The mathematical result of 999/998 is 0.9989989989...  Rounded to three decimal places, that *is* 0.999.  So if you use `%.3f` to print it, that's what you're going to get.

When you convert a floating-point number to integer in C, the fractional part is truncated.  So if you had the number 998.9989989 and you converted it to an int, you'd get 998.  So you can get the result you want by multiplying by 1000, truncating to an int, and dividing by 1000 again:

```
c = c * 1000;
c = (int)c;
c = c / 1000;
```

Or you could shorten that to

```
c = (int)(c * 1000) / 1000.;
```

This will work fine for problems such as 998/999 ≈ 0.998, but you're close to the edge of where type `float`'s limited precision will start introducing its own rounding issues.  Using `double` would be a better choice.  (Type `float`'s limited precision almost *always* introduces issues.)

Comment: This is subject to rounding errors in the multiplication. One correct solution, if the C implementation provides correctly rounded conversions in the formatted I/O functions, is to `sprintf` to a buffer with enough digits to represent the exact value, then take only the desired first digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point about the rounding.  Answer updated.